# Laravel 5. Save many-to-many

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have `products` table with the following content:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+
| id | product_name |     brand     |
+----+--------------+---------------+
|  1 | Jacket       | Zara          |
|  2 | Jacket       | Gucci         |
|  3 | Towel        | Zara          |
|  4 | Towel        | Pull and Bear |
|  5 | Towel        | Levi's        |
+----+--------------+---------------+
```

And `shopping_list_items` with the following content:

```
+----+------------+--------------+----------+
| id | product_id | product_type | quantity |
+----+------------+--------------+----------+
|  1 | NULL       | Jacket       |        1 |
|  2 | NULL       | Towel        |        1 |
+----+------------+--------------+----------+
```

I set relationship Many-to-Many:

```
Product model

public function shopListType()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Shopping_list_item::class, 'product_shopping_list_item', 'product_name', 'product_type');
    }

Shopping_list_item model

public function productType()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_shopping_list_item', 'product_type', 'product_name');
    }
```

So when I add an item to `shopping_list_items` table I want to save relation to `products` table through `product_shopping_list_item`.

Here is what I have in my Controller:

```
public function addShoppingListItem2(Request $request, Product $product)
    {      
            $shop_list = $id;

            $shopping_list_item = Shopping_list_item::firstorNew(['shopping_list_id' => $shop_list->id, 'product_type' => $request->product]);

            $shopping_list_item->quantity = $request->quantity;
            $shopping_list_item->product_type = $request->product;

            $product->shopListType()->save($shopping_list_item);
        }
```

But I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'product_type' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `shopping_list_items`
>   (`shopping_list_id`, `product_type`, `quantity`) values (13, ,1))

Why is `product_type` null if I set it? If relationship set correctly?

Comment: Are you sure `$request->product` is not empty in the first place?

Comment: Yes, it is not empty

Comment: You need to rethink your database structure. I think that what you need is a products table, a shopping_lists table (containing just list ID and list name or something, maybe a link to a customer table), and then a product_shopping_list table with just the product_id and the shopping_list_id.  There is no need to put things like the product_id into the shopping_lists table.

Think about this conceptually.  You have products, you have carts, and you have some products which can appear in one or more carts.

Comment: @delatbabel i have shopping_list table, but in this case it is not important. I have connection between product and shopping_list_item tables on id level that works fine. But I also need connection on product type level.

Comment: Hi @SvetoslavDimitrov -- I would suggest that if you have a connection between the product table and shopping_list_items table on the id level then you don't also need that connection on product type level because the product type is in the product table and you can fetch it using the join.

Comment: Perhaps it might help to publish your full database structure and we can comment on it as well as indicate the correct laravel code to update the relevant tables and columns.

Comment: @delatbabel in the end I did like this, but I am sure there should be a better solution :)